# How to find match number from comma separated numbers using sql query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table with comma separated number as datatype varchar(200) like this:

[image]

Now I am passing parameter like comma separated number to my query for get a output like below:

```
Id      MatchNumber
```

```
1       286
1       133
1       338
3       152
8       161
8       133
10      144
10      139
10      177
```

I have tried this SQL Query:

```
DECLARE @Ids varchar(50);
SET @Ids = '286,133,338,215,152,378,161,144,139,177';
select * from TblMMGameCard where Id IN (@Ids);
```

I want a output like above table. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  One option is to parse the search string and then test for the hit via a JOIN

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Ids varchar(50) = '286,530,338,215';

Select A.ID
      ,MatchNumber = B.RetVal 
 From  TblMMGameCard  A
 Join (
        Select RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')))
        From  (values  (cast('<x>' + replace(@IDs,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)))A(x)
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
      ) B  on charindex(','+RetVal+',',','+[cardNumbers]+',')>0
```

Comment: Thank @John Cappelletti

Comment: @Abhilash.J.A Always happy to help